# Configuring Android phones from PC

Tags: android, configuration-management

I am looking for a pc app that allows me to configure 5-10 android phones to have the same wifi settings, apps etc.

Is there such app available?

Comment: if there is nothing like this, at least adb and a script comes in my mind...

Comment: Could you provide some more details? E.g., are all those devices the same brand, model and Android version? Do you have ADB available? If yes to all, first thing coming to my mind is `adb backup` and `adb restore`. And the "how to" would best suit our Android sister site :)

Comment: @Izzy: if you talked to me... yes, i would if i could (easily)! - i never used `adb` extensively, just for flashing. -- i just wanted to point in this direction because i know `adb shell|install|backup|restore|...` is the way to go(, if there is no special software for this).

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Thanks, but I in fact was addressing the OP (or I had "pinged" you :) But now you're talking about it: indeed, some details on your suggestion are welcome as well #D And I bet for flashing you've rather used `fastboot`? // Mentioning `adb install` (which would work for apps) rings another bell: **gyurisc,** are those devices rooted? That would be required for pushing configs separately (other than via `adb restore`).

Comment: @Izzy: for sure i use `fastboot` for flashing itself, but during the whole process of flashing i use `adb` from time to time... **//** inspired by this question [i posted one on Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/167687/154901). hopefully an android-pro will post a good answer. **;-)**

Comment: These are not rooted devices but standard Samsung phones. I would like to install the same apps, settings but without rooting if possible

Comment: @gyurisc Samsung has quite a few different models. If you want to restore a complete backup from one to another, it must not just be the same brand, but the same model and Android version. That's why I was asking. So please be specific :)

Comment: I would need to work with Samsung S5, S6, S7. It is more like deploying/pushing settings apps to the phone. I am thinking of using some apps that are capable of using Samsung Know...